# Does changing the World Size option affect the size and number of locations that are not on the main map?

Tags: dont-starve

There is an option for World Size when you start a new game and click World, and this affects the size of the main map.  But, does it also affect the secondary worlds, such as Adventure mode world, Ruins and Caves?

Also, since the main world is bigger, will there be more such secondary location entrances?

Comment: I posted this on the [Klei Don't Starve forum](http://forums.kleientertainment.com/topic/31023-does-the-world-size-affect-the-size-of-adventure-mode-or-caves/) for you.

Answer (score 1):

I posted this question on the Klei Forum and I got the response that:

No, it does not affect the size of caves, etc.  Nor does it increase the number of sinkholes.

[Here is the response.](http://forums.kleientertainment.com/topic/31023-does-the-world-size-affect-the-size-of-adventure-mode-or-caves/)